# Problem defining appropriate measure in report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

The table below indicates a minimal example of my raw data:

| Product | Order Day | Customer | Units Ordered | Units Delivered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P | Apr 1 | X | 4 | 3 |
| P | Apr 2 | X | 4 | 3 |
| P | Apr 1 | Y | 3 | 1 |
| P | Apr 1 | Z | 3 | 1 |
| Q | Apr 1 | Z | 3 | 1 |
| Q | Apr 2 | W | 3 | 2 |
| R | Apr 3 | X | 1 | 0 |
| R | Apr 4 | Y | 2 | 0 |
| R | Apr 5 | Z | 8 | 8 |
| R | Apr 6 | Z | 6 | 6 |

Based on this I am able to create the following table as a PBI report where I give a **product summary**:

| Product | # diff. Customers Ordered | Total Ordered | Total Delivered | Service Rate | Product-level Service Test |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P | 3 | 14 | 8 | 0.57 | 1 |
| Q | 2 | 6 | 3 | 0.5 | 0 |
| R | 3 | 17 | 14 | 0.82 | 1 |

This final column in the above summary checks whether more then 50% is being delivered. This report can be filtered on Order Day (time filter) as well as Customers.

Now, in a similar fashion, I would like to create a **customer summary** report:

| Customer | # diff. Products Ordered | # Products Passing Service Test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2 | 1 |
| Y | 2 | 0 |
| Z | 3 | 1 |
| W | 1 | 1 |

It basically summarizes the product report after filtering for specific customers. My problem is the final column called "Products Passing Service Test". I am not able to define an appropriate measure in order to get the right numbers displayed in this column. I tried some other approaches but then it does not work well with the time filter on Customer Orders.

Anyone that can help? Thank you very much!

JD

Comment: FYI, a calculated column *cannot* interact with slicers or report filters since it is only calculated once when your data model is loaded rather than in response to report interactions.